# What was your main selling point to start your own research group after the PostDoc phase?

Tags: postdocs, funding, career-path, assistant-professor

I am in the PostDoc phase in an European institution where I am given quite some autonomy by the group leader. She is very generous indeed. Recently, she advised me to apply for a 4-5 year grant to start my own (small) research group within the same group. The field is computer science.

I want to ask those of you who have been successful in doing something similar in the past: What were those 2-3 main points in your proposal that made the cut for you?

Was it a current hot topic? Was it your overwhelming expertise? Was it the support environment? Was it the newness of your idea?

I know such an application necessarily needs a very good publication record, support from the institution, and so on, but I want to know the selling point from the proposal writing perspective.

What was the tone of your proposal writing?

What made your proposal irresistible to accept?

Comment: This is too broad to be answerable. It's also probably impossible for most people to know what aspects of an application made it successful.